# Gmail like Flip animation get's interrupted if second animation starts

Tags: java, android, animation

I have implemented an Android listview with flip checkboxes (GMail style) as shown here: http://techiedreams.com/gmail-like-flip-animated-multi-selection-list-view-with-action-mode/

The problem I have (even in the source code example): If there are multiple items I click/check in a fast sequence, the previous animation stops and will be restared. In other words, the previous animation does not finish and is interrupted by the second one.

Simple download the source code and try it on your own. In comparisson to gmail all animations, no matter how fast I'm clicking, are performed from the start to the end.

I can't find the piece of code in the demo source code to change this behaviour.

Any hints?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

This is the closest I could get to Gmail's flip animation:

In the getView() method (I'm using contextual action mode):

```
        holder.check.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (mActionMode == null) {
                            checked = new SparseBooleanArray(alllists.size());
                            mActionMode = ((Activity) getActivity()).startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
                            animateRow(position);
                            checked.put(position, true);
                            mActionMode.setTitle("1");
                            mActionMode.getMenu().getItem(0).setVisible(true);
                        } else {
                            animateRow(position);
                            if (checked.get(position)) {
                                checked.put(position, false);
                                if (checked.indexOfValue(true) < 0) {
                                    mActionMode.finish();

                                } else {
                                    mActionMode.setTitle(String.valueOf(getCheckedCount()));

                                }
                            } else {
                                checked.put(position, true);
                                mActionMode.setTitle(String.valueOf(getCheckedCount()));

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                                       );
```

Then the animateRow() method:

```
private void animateRow(final int position) {
    if (position >= listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() && position <= listView.getLastVisiblePosition()) {
        Log.i("animateRow", String.valueOf(position));
        ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(1, 0, 1, 1, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, 0, 0);
        anim.setDuration(150);
        anim.setRepeatCount(1);
        anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);

        viewa = listView.getChildAt(position - listView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
        final Button chkButton = (Button) viewa.findViewById(R.id.logo);

        if (checked.get(position)) {
            anim.setAnimationListener(
                    new AnimationListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                            Log.i("anim" + position, "Start");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                            Log.i("anim" + position, "Repeat" + animation.getRepeatCount());
                            viewa.setBackgroundResource(R.color.row_background);
                            chkButton.setBackgroundResource(R.color.button_background);
                            chkButton.setText(String.valueOf(alllists.get(position).itemsCount));
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                            Log.i("anim" + position, "END");

                        }
                    }
                                     );
            chkButton.startAnimation(anim);

        } else {

            anim.setAnimationListener(
                    new AnimationListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                            Log.i("anim" + position, "Start");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                            viewa.setBackgroundResource(R.color.checked_row_background);
                            chkButton.setBackgroundResource(R.color.checked_button_background);
                            chkButton.setText("✓");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                            Log.i("anim" + position, "END");

                        }
                    }
                                     );
            chkButton.startAnimation(anim);

        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Now you can forget that method to flip a view, since I've developed a new library [FlipView](https://github.com/davideas/FlipView) fully customizable, this is exactly what you want. You will be able to swap any kind of views and layouts with any kind of animation you desire.

Please have a look.